# Interpolate without system.Drawing

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, interpolation

I need to resize small images (favicons) to nearly 300%. so the quality is terrible. is there any way to adjust the quality without system.drawing (not available for wp7 atm)?

Comment: You simply can't resize small images to large images with good quality.

Comment: Good quality image means image with lots of details. And where would those details come from? They are not present in the small image.

Comment: "In the mathematical field of numerical analysis, interpolation is a method of constructing new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points."

Comment: Yeah, you can interpolate, but you won't get good quality by doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

However, scaling *up* never results in a higher quality image.  Or, to put it another way: you can't scale up and achieve "good" quality.  You are much better off providing a high quality image and scaling down.

Comment: it's difficult to get a high quality picture out of a favicon ^^

Comment: @roqstr: it already is a high quality picture...just 16x16 pixels. It does not store more information than required, thus you cannot expect it to produce "high quality" images at larger sizes.